# Remove empty values from CSV in Reporting services

Tags: csv, reporting-services

how i can remove empty value when i export my SSRS report into CSv format.
For example i got

```
PlayerId,F1,F2,Date,F3,F4
,,,,,
```

when my report is empty and i exported it to csv format

[MyReport](http://www.filedropper.com/netrefer)

Comment: What report items your report contains? I mean, output of what report item you want to remove?

Comment: So if PlayerId is empty(,) them to not show in csv the whole row

Comment: So you use table and want to hide rows if there no values in them?

Comment: Yes, but when i open the report i see only header and it's ok, But when i export to csv the same report i get ,,,, for empty values. And i want to hide that ,,,, values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to manipulate with visibility of rows. I reproduced your issue and solved it hiding rows if there is no data.

Right-click on row handle and select Row visibility:

[image]

and then set expression for Hidden property:

```
=Fields!PlayerId.IsMissing
```

Then, if value for this field will be missing, whole row will be hidden. If you need, you can make more complex expression, checking additional fields. If you need to hide rows only when exporting to CSV, you can do this:

```
=Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "CSV" And Fields!OrderId.IsMissing
```

In case of your file the element

```
<TablixMember>
  <Group Name="Details" />
</TablixMember>
```

should be

```
<TablixMember>
  <Group Name="Details" />
  <Visibility>
    <Hidden>=Fields!PlayerId.IsMissing</Hidden>
  </Visibility>
</TablixMember>
```

Comment: This doesn't solved my problem. I tried =Fields!PlayerId.IsMissing and also =Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "CSV" And Fields!PlayerId.IsMissing, but still the problem is there. What you have in the report server cofig file ?

Comment: The report server config is untouched from installation. Is has CSV render extension added. For what item you've set Hidden expression?

Comment: For PlayerId field. It's first field in my table and in that field is empty (,) then i want to hide all empty values in csv

Comment: No that solution doesn't help me at all. I tried also with just =Globals!RenderFormat.Name = "CSV" , but the result was the same (,,,,,)

Comment: OK, can you post the RDL content which is able to reproduce the issue?

Comment: I cannot past the whole code here. Plus i don't see any button for attaching the whole file. I figure out that problem only appears when i export to csv and i open the file like Excel CSV. If i open it with notepad(in notepad++ is the same problem like excel csv) the ,,, disappear. Any suggestion ?

Comment: You can post the file as code snippet. So you're saying that if you'll open the file with notepad++ it will have ,,, but usual windows notepad no? If you open the file in Excel first, it may be Excel specific behavior, I think that it can add this empty line. What if open file with notepad and notepad++ right after exporting?

Comment: Ok i uploaded the file. check the link in the post

Comment: You didn't set visibility for the row member (row itself). Try to edit file directly (I mean edit xml). I updated the answer with details what to do.

Comment: I figure out what was the problem.Export to CSV works even if i don't put Row visibility.Problem was with Reporting services service pack. I had older version. Thanks anyway

Comment: It's good when the update fixes the issue, not introduces new issues:)